# Performance difference between measure name and tags

Tags: influxdb

I have an IoT application where all data comes from the different sensors with a standard payload where all that changes is the variable ID which is a four digit hex string.

I currently use something like data.varID as my measurement name. The varID is also a tag, even if redundant. But this is somewhat inconvenient as some times I want to be able to easily query data across more than one varID.

I have tried to find the answer to this question but cannot find it: what’s the difference between

- having lots of data.varID measurements

Or

- have a single data measurement with varID as a tag

As I understand, both would be equivalent in terms of the number of time series in the database so is there any other consideration?

The types of queries I usually need are simple:

```
SELECT "value" FROM "db1"."autogen"."data.org1.global.5051" WHERE time > now() - 24h AND ("device"='d--0000-0000-0000-0acf' OR "device"='d--0000-0000-0000-0ace')
```

so basically getting data for a given variable across devices for a period of time. But in some cases, I also want to get more that one variable at a time, which is why I would like to instead do something like:

```
SELECT "value" FROM "db1"."autogen"."data.org1" WHERE time > now() - 24h AND ("device"='d--0000-0000-0000-0acf' OR "device"='d--0000-0000-0000-0ace') AND ("variable"="5051") AND ("variable"="5052")
```

but at this time, I would be putting everything on a single measurement, with "device", "variable" (and a couple other things) as tags.

So, is there any consideration I need to consider before switching to having a single measurement for my whole database?

Comment: It really depends on your use case... What operations will you have to perform on your data?

Comment: @FWeidinger Added a little more detail on OP

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody was able to answer this question, I will answer it the best I know understand it.

There does not seem to be any performance difference between one large measurement series Vs smaller measurement series.

But there is a critical difference, which in our case, ended up forcing us into multiple measurements:

In our case, while the schema between different measurements share the same fields, some measurements can have additional fields.

The problem is that fields seem to be associated to the measurement itself, so if we add

```
 data,device=0bd8,var=5053 value=10 1574173550390000
 data,device=0bd8,var=5053 value=10 1574173550400000
 data,device=0bd8,var=5054 foo=12,value=10 1574173550390000
 data,device=0bd8,var=5055 bar=10,value=10 1574173550390000
```

the fact that var `5054` has a `foo` field and `5055` has a `bar` field means that when you query any variable, you will get both `foo` and `bar` (set to None if they don't exist):

```
{'foo': None, 'bar': None}
```

This means that if you have 100 variables, and each add say, 5 custom fields, you will end up with 500 fields every time you query. And while this is not a storage issue, the fact that the fields are associated with the measurement means you will have an exponential growth on the JSON object returned by the database, even if most fields set to None.

If the schema was to be identical across all measurements, then it seems not to make a difference between using a single `data` measurement (with different tags) Vs. multiple `data.<var>` measurements.

Comment: Well, this only happens if you do not specify a field-key in your queries, so I don't think your conclusion is always fitting. If you were to run the following query ```SELECT "bar" from <measurement>"``` your query response would not return unspecified field-keys and therefore no ```None``` values.

Comment: At least in our case, we don’t control the schema so we would have to add all sort of additional functionality to require our users define the schema so the code knows how to retrieve the proper fields. Basically, we usually need to do SELECT *

Comment: Yep. Then certainly multiple measurements is the correct way to go for your Use Case.